# Using regexp to find 2 or more characters repeating sequentially

Tags: sql, regex, teradata

I'm trying to use teradata regexp to to find names where letters appear two or more times in succession

For example Smith and Simons should each return 0 , but Smmith, LLOYD, Smittth and Simmons should each return 1

I've tried:  regexp_instr(NameField,'(.)\1[1}')

But this only returns a value 1 if the double letters are at the start of the NameField - e.g. LLOYD, AAMIR  return 1 - but COLLINS returns 0

How can I 'trap' any occurrence of double letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have a typo. For whatever reason you used an opening square bracket for the quantifier
2. Make sure you're doing `> 0` for your comparison

```sql
regexp_instr(NameField,'(.)\1{1}') > 0
```

Realistically `{1}` is superfluous since `\1` is already a request for exactly one match.

Comment: `regexp_instr` will return the position of the match, or 0 if no match. `regexp_substr` will return the matching characters,  or null if no match.

Comment: Additionally, you're missing a closing square bracket

Comment: @Andrew ["If *source_string* is NULL, NULL is returned."](https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/hItZLLgV~69HKRwTjkNh8w) so would you need a check for `>0` in addition to `is not null` or does teradata treat null as always less than any integer? even negative ones.

Comment: @Andrew That was copy+pasted from OP. Maybe OP's issue is just a typo...

Comment: `> 0` should work for regexp_instr.  I just find regexp_substr a little cleaner.

Comment: A comparison such as `NULL > 0` is neither `true` nor `false`, it is unknown i.e. `NULL`.

Comment: @Fred Is this explicitly for Teradata? In JS `alert(null > -1);` is `true` whereas `alert(null > 0);` is `false`. PHP produces `false` for both scenarios.

Comment: Standard SQL 3-value logic; applies to most relational databases. In particular, note that _both_ `NOT (NULL > 0)` and `NULL > 0` will evaluate to `NULL`. For constructs like `WHERE` the semantics are defined based on the entire expression being `true` or something else (`false`,`NULL`).

Comment: Thank you - exactly what I needed, a very clear explanation- and yes that was a typo, { & [ share the same key on my keyboard

Answer (score 0):

```
(.)\1
```

I think this is what you're looking for. `(.)` captures any character and `\1` captures a character if it matches the previous one, i.e. a double letter